# How do I convert a date to build a graph? np.linspace

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, streamlit

Using streamlit, I enter date data so that a graph is built on it. Doing it for the first time. I get this error.

`datetime.date' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

As I understand, the date needs to be converted somehow. But don't throw stones, I don't know how)

```
def SIR(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R = y
        dSdt = -beta * S * I / N
        dIdt = beta * S * I / N - gamma * I
        dRdt = gamma * I
        return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt

  st.subheader("Date parameters")

    today = datetime.date.today()
    tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    one_day = tomorrow - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    start = st.date_input('Start date')
    end = st.date_input('End date', tomorrow)
    last = st.date_input('Last date', one_day)

    if start < end:
        st.success('Start date: `%s`\n\nEnd date: `%s`\n\n' % (start, end))
    else:
        st.error('Error: End date must fall after start date.')

    if last < end:
        st.success('Last date: `%s`\n\nEnd date: `%s`\n\n' % (last, end))
    else:
        st.error('Error: End date must fall after last date.')

    t = np.linspace(start, last, end)

ret = odeint(SIR, y0, t, args=(N, beta, gamma))

    S, I, R = ret.T

    def plotsir(t, S, I, R):
        f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 4))
        ax.plot(t, S, 'b', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Susceptible')
        ax.plot(t, I, 'y', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Infected')
        ax.plot(t, R, 'g', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Recovered')

        ax.set_xlabel('Time (days)')

        ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
        ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
        ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
        legend = ax.legend()
        legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
        for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
            ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
            st.pyplot()

    if st.button("Show Plot SIR"):
        st.text("Enjoy")
        plotsir(t, S, I, R)
```

Previously just drove three numerical values

```
t = np.linspace(0, 49, 50)
```

[image: plot]

I understand that streamlit is indirectly affected here. I'm really confused.

Comment: "everything does not fit into the comments" nor should it. The comments are only for short questions and answers that lead to editing the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because `np.linspace` is looking for integers as its input. It's not for creating a range with dates.

Use something like [`pd.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) from pandas to make a date range.

```py
>>> pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
               '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried, but I'm getting confused, can you tell me more?

Comment: The code you've provided above doesn't show what it is you're trying to do, and Streamlit is a tangent here to trying to create a graph.

What chart are you trying to create? Where does the Y axis data come from, and you want to plot that data by date?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I supplemented the question. I just can't figure it out.